# Google tag manager with react +redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, google-tag-manager

I have integrated GTM with react & redux  , I also tried to react-google-tag-manager but it is not working in my application.

Below is my component in which onClick of "Read More" ,I am hitting one event and pushing data to dataLayer but after that if i click anywhere in application it is firing same old event.

Below is my code -

```
  _toggleNews(post) {
    let gtmEvent = {
            'action': 'Live News',
            'actionValue': {
                nugget_id: post.nugget_id ? post.nugget_id : '',
                event_title: post.event_title ? post.event_title : '',
                event_link: post.event_link ? post.event_link : ''
            }
    }
     dataLayer.push(gtmEvent);
 }
  render() {
    let post = this.props.post
    return (
        <li>
          <a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick={this._toggleNews.bind(this, post)}>Read More</a>
            </div>
        </li>
     )
   }
```

And in my index.html i have added GTM code.
It is triggering same event if we not clicked on Read More . May be data Layer is not getting empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not an issue of which module you are using. In onClick, you are calling the function in a wrong way.

```
onClick={()=>this._toggleNews.bind(this, post)}
```

You need to add () in onClick.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should reset the datalayer. Try this recommendation from [this tweet of Simo Ahava's](https://twitter.com/SimoAhava/status/823753362843770888);

> `google_tag_manager[“GTM-XXXX”].dataLayer.reset()` will clear GTM’s internal data model.